# What is the 'z' in kana character?

Tags: kana

What is the 'z' in kana character?

The context cartoon image:https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=66989588

[image: the screenshot of the 'z' character]

Comment: I assume you mean the z-like character. If so, it's で.

Answer (score 7):

It says:

> 「でろーーーん・・・」

There is no "z" in it.

「でろん/デロン」 is an onomatopoeia used to describe something flabby, pliable, soft, etc.  Just think of Gudetama.

Synonymous onomatopoeias would be 「グニャグニャ」、「グネグネ」, etc.